# React Echarts Line Chart Dynamic Data chart animation wont scroll

Tags: reactjs, echarts

I am just starting to work with ECharts in my React application.  I have a need where I want a line graph and have it update once a second with dynamic data.  I have it working, but the animation on updates moves each data point vertically instead of scrolling the whole graph like it does in the sample graphs without using React.

Here is what mine currently looks like when it updates:
[image: My app graph]

Here is what the example app looks like, and how I would like my graph to animate:
[image: ECharts Example]

You can see a code example here that updates everytime you hit the button.

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/echarts-playground-forked-xvrj6j?file=/src/App.js)

Is there a way to do this?

}Dan